# Set CSS to dynamically created class

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

I have multiple `<ul>` and their class names are pulled from database. User can add or delete those unordered lists and give them any name they wish. Then user can assign color to every `<ul>`. I can save color to database but I don't know how to load it to css because I have to select class which name I don't know and set some color to `background-color` atribute.
This is how I load list:

```
<ul class="<?php echo $stringTemp; ?>">
```

This is placed in `while` loop. Now I need help to put background color to each of these lists.

Comment: Can you show the whole code including the SQL query and others ?

Comment: @Alen: You can use a template library like underscore , duster or mustache. It's easy to do in that. Provided you have the data on the page load.

Comment: Use inline css <ul style='background-color:$stringTemp;'>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uhm, just `style="background-color: xxx"` ?

Comment: Will this work for mutliple styles. I have to set gradient but since gradient is part of CSS3 I have to make seperate styles for multiple browsers?

Comment: You can see the standard syntax [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient). Browser support [here](http://caniuse.com/css-gradients).

Comment: @Alen multiple styles as in multiple properties? Sure: `style="background-color: xxx; background-image: -webkit-xxx; background-image: -moz-xxx;"`

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
echo "<style>
           .myClass {
                background-color:$stringTemp;
            }
 </style>";

 echo "<ul class='$myClass'>       </ul>";

 ?>
```

Comment: I like this better than mine but you put `.myClass` in the PHP instead of `. " . $myClass . " {`.  +1 though

Answer (score 0):

Make a file called `style.css` and put this in it:

```
ul.class-one { background-color: #000; }
ul.class-two { background-color: #F00; }
ul.class-etcetc...
```

and add this to your HTML `<head>` section:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/html" src="style.css">
```

You probably know how to do this already I just want to be thorough for others reading this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one it

```
<?php

        while()
        {
    echo"<ul class='".$stringTemp."'>";
        }
?>
```